# How to read cookies from localhost?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a Chrome Extension, and the first step is to determine whether the user is logged into my website. For development, I'm testing against `localhost`, so how do I read the write cookies?

Here's what's in my manifest:

```
"permissions": [
    "cookies", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
],
```

And the JavaScript is:

```
chrome.cookies.get({"url": 'localhost', "name": '_ga'}, function(cookie) {
    console.log('cookie:');
    console.log(cookie);
});
```

But I get this error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running cookies.get: Invalid url: "localhost".
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Ah, that was the problem. Please post as the answer so I can accept! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost` is not a valid URL; it is merely a [perceived] host name.

Use `http://localhost`, with the protocol included, for the URL.